# How to Convert simple link

Tags: javascript, authentication, hyperlink

example : <a href="http://deomarvin.com">Download</a> convert to
If you are not logged in. convert to <a href="http://deomarvin.com/login">Login</a>
if you are logged in. convert to <a href="http://deomarvin.com">Download</a>

Comment: Learn one web programming language.

Answer (score 0):

**Pseudo code**:

```
if (!logged) {
  <a href="http://deomarvin.com/login">Login</a>
}
else {
  <a href="http://deomarvin.com">Download</a>
}
```

Comment: no no! Automatically replace the text links if already logged in or before login such as forum . How ?

Answer (score 0):

It of course depends on how you are verifying whether or not the user is logged in (which probably shouldn't be done with javascript)! In your PHP file or ASP file or some other place... you would need to do something like...

```
if (logged_in()) {
  echo 'download';
} else {
  echo 'login';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
 <a href="http://deomarvin.com" id="downld">Download</a>
```

JS:

```
 if(!loggedin){
  document.getElementById('downld').innerHTML="Login"
 }
```

If you don't have write access to the HTML, use this JS:

```
 if(!loggedin){
 var a=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
 for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
  try{
   if(a[i].innerHTML=="Download"){
    a[i].innerHTML="Login";
   }
  }catch(e){}
 }
 }
```

Note that this will convert *every* link with "Download" in it.

Note that javascript should *never* be handling login stuff. This makes more sense when done through PHP/ASP/JSP (just echo/print the correct link based on the login). JS logins are easy to hack.

Comment: @tomw I see what you did there. ;-) Fact is, many of my initial posts in SO were based on what I'd seen on other SO answers(I was a Physics.SE member first). So I didn't know about all this. After spending some time on MSO, I realized that my "role model" posts were all bad examples. I'll fix or delete these posts later (tomorrow), on mobile right now.

Comment: Since I don't plan in being too active on SO, I've basically decided to use my rep constructively--downvote bad posts (too many people have complained about this on MSO).  Hopefully, some will learn from my comments :)

Comment: The thing is that I felt no explanation was needed there because he wanted to unescape it so I said "try this instead". In any case, thought it was fun to do it back on one of your own old post to make you feel how I do. In any case, comments & downvotes have been reverted. And yeah, I do get the point though, should have linked him to the Handlebars documentation. Editing my (reposted) answer again...

Comment: @tom great! I don't really get affected by the downvotes, I don't care about rep. I'll fix em anyway..